# Convert Python code to PHP/Laravel (Gate.io signature)

Tags: python, php, hash

I am in the process of incorporating the gate,io rest api and am currently trying to convert the signature function from python to php(laravel).

Apparently there is a bug hiding in the conversion.

Can someone take a look and tell me if this is all correct or if something is missing here?

For improvement suggestions I would be grateful

Python code:

```
def gen_sign(method, url, query_string=None, payload_string=None):
    key = ''        # api_key
    secret = ''     # api_secret

    t = time.time()
    m = hashlib.sha512()
    m.update((payload_string or "").encode('utf-8'))
    hashed_payload = m.hexdigest()
    s = '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (method, url, query_string or "", hashed_payload, t)
    sign = hmac.new(secret.encode('utf-8'), s.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    return {'KEY': key, 'Timestamp': str(t), 'SIGN': sign}
```

Source: [Gate.io API Signature string generation](https://www.gate.io/docs/developers/apiv4/en/#apiv4-permissions)

Php Code:

```
public function createSignature($method, $url, $query=null, $payload=null, $algo = 'sha256'){
        $key = 'xxx';
        $secret= 'xxx';

        $time = microtime(true);

        $hashed_payload = hash_hmac($algo,$query ?? '');

        $string = "{$methode}\n{$url}\n{$query ?? ''}\n{$hashed_payload}\n{$time}"
        
        $sign = hash_hmac($algo,$string,$secret)
       
        return ['KEY' => $key, 'Timestamp' => "{$time}", 'SIGN' => $sign]
    
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code does, but there is an official [PHP SDK](https://github.com/gateio/gateapi-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, i hope it will helps:

```
public function buildSignHeaders($method, $resourcePath, $queryParams = [], $payload = null)
    {
        $fullPath = parse_url(config('gate-io.host'), PHP_URL_PATH) . $resourcePath;
        $fmt = "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s";
        $timestamp = time();
        $hashedPayload = hash("sha512", ($payload !== null) ? $payload : "");
        $signatureString = sprintf(
            $fmt,
            $method,
            $fullPath,
            GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query($queryParams, false),
            $hashedPayload,
            $timestamp
        );
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha512", $signatureString, config('gate-io.apiSecretKey'));
        return [
            "KEY" => config('gate-io.apiKey'),
            "SIGN" => $signature,
            "Timestamp" => $timestamp
        ];
    }
```